# SQL Stored Procedure datetime filter by location

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, filter

I have a problem with a stored procedure in SQL Server, there is a table with two datetime columns, a start time and an end time that I am filtering on based on location and entity.

In a location report, when the filtering conditions for Start time and End time are set, only location records where the start time is at least as great as the filtering Start time and the end time is no later than the filtering End time are considered in building the report.  For example if in reality John Doe was in Room A from 8:30 to 9:30 and then in Room B from 9:30 until 10:30, a report of locations from 9:00 to 10:00 will include no record of John Doe's whereabouts.

The desired behavior is that location intervals (as opposed to individual location records) that begin before the End time and end after the Start time should be included.  In terms of presentation, in the case of John Doe above, the output report should show John Doe in Room A from 9:00 to 9:30 and in Room B from 9:30 to 10:00, imposing the filtering limits when the limits of the location interval are not within the filtering constraints.

Is this at all possible? If there is any other information needed please let me know, at the moment I'm using a basic AND locationchangehistory.starttime >= Starttime AND locationchangehistory.endtime <= @Endtime)

This is the full Stored Procedure the company is using, I hope the formatting comes out correctly:-

```
                     @Asset Varchar (MAX) = NULL OUTPUT, 
                     @Location Varchar (MAX) = NULL OUTPUT,
                     @Ward Varchar (MAX) = NULL OUTPUT,
                     @Zone Varchar (MAX) = NULL OUTPUT,
                     @Floor Varchar (MAX) = NULL OUTPUT,
                     @Starttime datetime OUTPUT,
                     @Endtime datetime OUTPUT,
                     @Top int,
                     @FacilityID int

                     AS
                     SELECT DISTINCT TOP (@Top)


                     location.name AS 'Location', 
                     monitoredentity.name AS 'Asset', 
                     zone.name AS 'Zone', 
                     floor.name AS 'Floor',
                     ward.name AS 'Area',
                     locationchangehistory.starttime AS 'Starttime', 
                     locationchangehistory.endtime AS 'Endtime', 
                     CONVERT(varchar(max), DATEDIFF(SECOND, 
                     locationchangehistory.starttime, locationchangehistory.endtime) / 3600) + ':' + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(2), DATEDIFF(SECOND, locationchangehistory.starttime, 
                     locationchangehistory.endtime) % 3600 / 60), 2) + ':' + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(2), DATEDIFF(SECOND, locationchangehistory.starttime, 
                     locationchangehistory.endtime) % 60), 2) AS 'TimeInPlace' 


                     FROM floor INNER JOIN
                     zone ON zone.floor = floor.id INNER JOIN
                     ward ON zone.id = ward.zone INNER JOIN
                     location ON ward.id = location.ward INNER JOIN
                     locationchangehistory ON location.id =                        locationchangehistory.location INNER JOIN
                     monitoredentity ON monitoredentity.id =    locationchangehistory.entity




                     WHERE 


                     (monitoredentity.type  =  4 
               AND   floor.facilityid = @FacilityID
               AND   zone.facilityid = @FacilityID
               AND   ward.facilityid = @FacilityID
               AND   Location.facilityid = @FacilityID
               AND   locationchangehistory.facility = @FacilityID
               AND   monitoredentity.facilityid = @FacilityID 
               AND  charindex(',' + cast(monitoredentity.id AS VARCHAR(MAX))                  + ',', ',' + @Asset + ',') > 0
               AND locationchangehistory.starttime >= @Starttime 
               AND locationchangehistory.endtime <= @Endtime)
               AND ((charindex(',' + cast(Location.id AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ',', ',' + @location + ',') > 0 OR  charindex(',' + cast(Ward.id AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ',', ',' + @Ward + ',') > 0
               OR  charindex(',' + cast(zone.id AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ',', ',' + @Zone + ',') > 0) OR  charindex(',' + cast(floor.id AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ',', ',' + @Floor + ',') > 0)




                ORDER by locationchangehistory.starttime DESC`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just changed your select and where, try this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP (@Top)
                     location.name AS 'Location', 
                     monitoredentity.name AS 'Asset', 
                     zone.name AS 'Zone', 
                     floor.name AS 'Floor',
                     ward.name AS 'Area',
                     locationchangehistory.starttime AS 'Starttime', 
                     case when locationchangehistory.endtime<@Endtime then
                        locationchangehistory.endtime else
                            @Endtime
                        end  'Endtime', 
                     CONVERT(varchar(max), DATEDIFF(SECOND, 
                     locationchangehistory.starttime, locationchangehistory.endtime) / 3600) + ':' + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(2), DATEDIFF(SECOND, locationchangehistory.starttime, 
                     locationchangehistory.endtime) % 3600 / 60), 2) + ':' + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(2), DATEDIFF(SECOND, locationchangehistory.starttime, 
                     locationchangehistory.endtime) % 60), 2) AS 'TimeInPlace' 


                     FROM floor INNER JOIN
                     zone ON zone.floor = floor.id INNER JOIN
                     ward ON zone.id = ward.zone INNER JOIN
                     location ON ward.id = location.ward INNER JOIN
                     locationchangehistory ON location.id =                        locationchangehistory.location INNER JOIN
                     monitoredentity ON monitoredentity.id =    locationchangehistory.entity

               WHERE 

               locationchangehistory.starttime between locationchangehistory.starttime  and locationchangehistory.endtime
               AND locationchangehistory.endtime >= locationchangehistory.starttime

               AND (monitoredentity.type  =  4 
               AND   floor.facilityid = @FacilityID
               AND   zone.facilityid = @FacilityID
               AND   ward.facilityid = @FacilityID
               AND   Location.facilityid = @FacilityID
               AND   locationchangehistory.facility = @FacilityID
               AND   monitoredentity.facilityid = @FacilityID 
               AND  charindex(',' + cast(monitoredentity.id AS VARCHAR(MAX))                  + ',', ',' + @Asset + ',') > 0
               --AND locationchangehistory.starttime >= @Starttime 
               --AND locationchangehistory.endtime <= @Endtime)
               AND ((charindex(',' + cast(Location.id AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ',', ',' + @location + ',') > 0 OR  charindex(',' + cast(Ward.id AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ',', ',' + @Ward + ',') > 0
               OR  charindex(',' + cast(zone.id AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ',', ',' + @Zone + ',') > 0) OR  charindex(',' + cast(floor.id AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ',', ',' + @Floor + ',') > 0)
```

Comment: you'd be better off editing your existing answer and adding this to it rather than having 2 answers to the same question.

Comment: Thank you very much this was exactly what I was after, thanks to all for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

If I've gotten you right, you just need an OR-Opreator. With an AND Operator you want the condition to check BOTH boolean Expressions are true.

E.g.

A = 1 AND B = 1 means check if A is equal to 1 and if, and only if, A is true, it is useful to check if B was equal to 1, too. If the first Condition is not true, it wont get as far as the second condition, even though it was true.

An OR operation will check, if any of the both Conditions are true, and return the ROW if there was a hit for one of the conditions.

I like the following eplanation somehow:

```
- compare AND to a multiplication (*)
- Compare OR to a add operation (+)
- 1 and 0 are our boolean values
- so 0 * 1 = 0 and vice versa but 1*1 = 1
- 1 + 0 = 1, 0+1 and 1+1 = 1
```

Comment: I have forgotten 0*0 = 0 and 0+0 = 0

Answer (score 0):

For sample data, I have created the table below and insert the records in it.

```
create table #time_managment
(Empid char(21),Location char(65), timeIN time,OUTtime time)
```

Insert goes here.

```
insert into #time_managment
values('John Doe','Development Room','8:00','8:30')
insert into #time_managment
values('John Doe','INtegration Room','8:40','9:30')
insert into #time_managment
values('John Doe','QA Room','10:00','11:30')
```

Below selects will show all the data in the table and the one with time range of `7:00` to `11:00`. By using `case` we can show the timeout/end time with in the desired range of time.

```
select * from #time_managment
select Empid,Location,timeIN,
case when OUTTime<'11:00' then
    OUTTime
else
    '11:00'
end      from #time_managment
where timeIN between '7:00' and '11:00'
and OUTtime >=timeIN
```

Comment: I hope it looks better to you now Tanner.